# How to get the highest row and column of a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, math, methods

I'm stuck on a problem where I am supposed to make a method that returns the row with the highest average number in a 2D array

The method that I attached here only gets the averages of each row.
I believe that I need to keep track the row with the highest average but I just don't know how
Any suggestions?

```
int[][] array = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };

public static double getRowAverage(int grid[][]) {
    int i, j;
    double sum = 0, average = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            sum = sum + grid[i][j];
        }
        average=sum/grid[i].length;
        System.out.println("Average of row " + (i+1) + " = " + average); 
        sum=0;
        double a = i+1;
    }
    return average;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166). This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE]. Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, clarifies what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can start by adding a variable named `max` and set it to 0 at the top of the method. Then each iteration, check if the row's average is more than the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare and check if the row average is higher than the current highest

```
double rowAverage = sum / grid[i].length;
average = rowAverage > average ? rowAverage : average;
```

or even better, use `Math.max`

```
average = Math.max(average, sum / grid[i].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some notes regarding the code in your question.

- As well as `sum`, you also need to zero `average` for each new row.
- No need to declare loop variables `i` and `j` outside of the loop.
- Java has "short-circuit" statements like `+=`.
- I understand that the purpose of this line:

```java
double a = i+1;
```

is to store the index of the row (in the `grid`) that contains the highest average. That variable should be `int` (and not `double`) since a row index can only be an `int`. The variable should also be declared outside of the outer `for` loop since you can only know its final value after you have processed all the rows in `grid`. In the code below, I renamed `a` to `maxRow`.

- You need another variable to store the maximum.

Note that I assume that all the integers in `grid` are positive – as per the example in your question.

```java
public class Averages {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
        double maxAvg = 0.0;
        int maxRow = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            double sum = 0, average = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                sum += grid[i][j];
            }
            average = sum / grid[i].length;
            if (average > maxAvg) {
                maxAvg = average;
                maxRow = i;
            }
            System.out.println("Average of row " + (i+1) + " = " + average);
        }
        System.out.println("Row with highest average: " + (maxRow + 1));
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
Average of row 1 = 2.0
Average of row 2 = 5.0
Average of row 3 = 8.0
Row with highest average: 3
```

Comment: The average can be less than zero. Best to initialize to Double.MIN_VALUE